# Use of instance variables vs passing data as a parameter

Tags: java, android, performance, coding-style

What are the disadvantages when an instance variable is used instead of passing the data as a parameter.

Using instance variables seems more readable to me, but are there disadvantages of making them available to the whole class. I guess this is coming from global vs local variable perspective.

Using instance variables

```
public class ChoicesFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private CharSequence[] mButtonTextData;
    private String mTitleTextData;  
    
    private View mUserChoiceView;
    
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mUserChoiceView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.available_choices, container, false);

        getBundleData();

        setTitle();
        setButtons();        

        return  mUserChoiceView;
    }
    
    private void getBundleData() {
        //populate button text
        Bundle bundleData = getArguments();
        mTitleTextData = bundleData.getString(CardFragment.TITLE_TEXT_KEY);
        mButtonTextData = bundleData.getCharSequenceArray(CardFragment.BUTTON_TEXT_KEY);        
    }
    
    private void setTitle() {
        TextView title = (TextView) mUserChoiceView.findViewById(R.id.choicesTextView1);
        String genericTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.title_selection);
        title.setText(genericTitle + mTitleTextData);
    }

    //sets up button data
    public void setButtons() {
        TextView[] buttonsTextView = new TextView[4];
        buttonsTextView[0] = (TextView) mUserChoiceView.findViewById(R.id.choicesTextView2);
        buttonsTextView[1] = (TextView) mUserChoiceView.findViewById(R.id.choicesTextView3);
        buttonsTextView[2] = (TextView) mUserChoiceView.findViewById(R.id.choicesTextView4);
        buttonsTextView[3] = (TextView) mUserChoiceView.findViewById(R.id.choicesTextView5);

        for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            buttonsTextView[i].setText(mButtonTextData[i]);
        }
    }   
}
```

Second example pass the data as parameters

```
public class ChoicesFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener { 
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {                            
        View userChoiceView;
                             
        String titleTextData;
        CharSequence[] buttonTextData;
        
        mUserChoiceView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.available_choices, container, false);

        Bundle bundleData = getArguments();
        buttonTextData = bundleData.getString(CardFragment.TITLE_TEXT_KEY);
        titleTextData = bundleData.getCharSequenceArray(CardFragment.BUTTON_TEXT_KEY);

        setTitle(userChoiceView, titleTextData);
        setButtons(userChoiceView, buttonTextData);        

        return  mUserChoiceView;
    }
    
    private void setTitle(View userChoiceView, String titleText) {
        TextView title = (TextView) userChoiceView.findViewById(R.id.choicesTextView1);
        String genericTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.title_selection);
        title.setText(genericTitle + titleText);
    }

    //sets up button data
    public void setButtons(View userChoiceView, CharSequence[] buttonText) {
        TextView[] buttonsTextView = new TextView[4];
        buttonsTextView[0] = (TextView) userChoiceView.findViewById(R.id.choicesTextView2);
        buttonsTextView[1] = (TextView) userChoiceView.findViewById(R.id.choicesTextView3);
        buttonsTextView[2] = (TextView) userChoiceView.findViewById(R.id.choicesTextView4);
        buttonsTextView[3] = (TextView) userChoiceView.findViewById(R.id.choicesTextView5);

        for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            buttonsTextView[i].setText(buttonText[i]);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Passing instance variables within **their own** class methods is pointless and over engineering IMO.

Comment: You are right, but that is not done in this example. The question is about instance variable **vs** parameters. And that's also what the examples are about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using parameters allows you to make the method self-contained.  You never have to wonder what value the instance variable has, because you passed the data as a parameter.

Apart from the very useful benefit of encapsulation, parameterized methods are far easier to unit test than methods that depend on the value of instance variables.

Comment: Well, unit-tests shouldn't be the cause for deciding whether to parameterize or not. You can always have a proper constructor, setters or inject the data through other means in order to have those instance variables properly initialized. There are so many ways for doing this...and no real "one way of doing it right (tm)" :)

Comment: These instance variables and methods are **members** of the same class. Why pass them around??? The encapsulation is achieved by the field access modifiers and the use of public methods to access hidden fields not by passing the fields into their own class methods.

Comment: @I.K. The question is instance vs parameter. That's what both question and answer are about. Passing the instance members as a parameter within the same instance is ridiculous.

Comment: @Mjoellnir if you make constructors and setters just for unit tests then isn't that just as bad as having variables that are used across the class and logically belong to the class, be used as method parameters?

Comment: @obesechicken13 if those constructors / setters are just for unit-testing, yes. That is just as undesirable. I usually use reflection in unit-tests if I run into the situation that I have to access / initialize / verify something during testing that should otherwise in production use not be accessed directly from outside or from sub-classes.